# Application of Calculus to medicine

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if there's a function or a derivative to model the following problem (since this problem is from a Calculus book) or it's solved just using the Rule of three with percentages

[image]

Comment: The derivative tells you the *instantaneous rate of change* of a quantity, so "rate of RBC loss" can be expressed as $f'(t)$, where $f(t)$ is the number of red blood cells at time $t$.

Comment: Could you write the name of the book?

Comment: This can be distilled down into fundamentally a complex interest problem so the RBC's lost decrease exponentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's begin with the first problem.

**1.** According to the info:

$$ \dfrac{dH}{dt} = kH, $$

with $H$ the volume of red blood cells. We also have:

$$H(t=0)=5*0.45=2.25\, \mathrm L, \quad \text{$t$ in hours}.$$

At the end, the patient has lost $2.5\, \mathrm L$ of blood, which means that the patient has $2.5\,\mathrm L$ of blood (remember that before the surgery the patient has $5\, \mathrm L$ of blood). In order to know $H(t= 4)$, we do the following:

$$2.5 * 0.45 = 1.125\, \mathrm L.$$

$1.125\, \mathrm L$ is the volume of red blood cells after $4$ hours.

**2.** For the second problem, a percentage of blood is extracted before the surgery. We denote it like this:

$$\text{blood extracted} = 5x, \quad \text{with $0\leq x \leq 1$}.$$

The remaining blood is:

$$ 5 - 5x,$$

and the volume of red blood cells is:

$$ 0.45(5 - 5x).$$

After $4$ hours, the patient has lost $2.5\, \mathrm L$, which means $5-5x-2.5$, so the volume of red blood cells he has lost is:

$$0.45(5-5x-2.5).$$

The concentration can never be allowed to drop below $25 \,\%$, therefore, the maximum amount of blood that can be extracted occurs when he has a concentration of red blood cells $0.25(5 -5 x)$ after $4$ hours. Putting all of this into an equation:

$$ 0.45(5 - 5x) - 0.45(5-5x-2.5) = 0.25(5 -5 x).$$

And $x=0.1$, the maximum amount of blood that can be extracted is $10\,\%$.

**3.** With this information, can you do the third problem?